# Differences between 場所 and どこの場所

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

In a short story the protagonist says this sentence:

> そして僕は突然、自分が知っている誰からも、自分が知っている**どこの場所**からも、信じられないくらい遠く隔てられ、引き離されているんだと感じる

I was wondering: why `自分が知っている**どこの場所**` instead of just `自分が知っている**場所**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand 誰からも in this sentence, this どこの場所からも is almost the same.

- 自分が知っている**誰**から**も**離される
  to be separated from **any**one I know
- 自分が知っている場所から離される
  to be separated from **a/the** place I know
- 自分が知っている**どこの**場所から**も**離される
  to be separated from **any** place I know

どこの場所 is a relatively uncommon combination, if not wrong. Usually どの場所からも, どんな場所からも or simply どこからも is used to say *from anywhere/everywhere*.